# UITableview small lag at third cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

This video demonstrates the issue I am having

[UITableView screen lag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNckP7bB6YE&feature=youtu.be)

I am loading a xib file with a fair bit of stackView and UIViews into my tableview cell. Each cell takes up about 80% of the screen so you would see two cells at max.

I am experiencing a small lag when I am scrolling to the third cell. If I scroll back up again and scroll down like what I did, the lag does not appear to be there anymore and the tableView scrolls smoothly for the remaining cell. If I reload the table and repeat the above step, I will get that lag again when third cell is just about to appear.

It "feels" like the program takes longer to load the xib file in cellForRowAtIndexPath for the very first time. And once it is loaded, it could be loaded nice and fast for any other cell. (That is just a feel though)

All my views have static data. I am finding that this small lag decrease as I removed more view from the xib file.

Is this pattern normal?

Note. In the video when I pull to refresh, the table is reloaded. I have reloaded the table just before the video starts. You will see that at the beginning and whenever third cell is just about to appear (or half way through scrolling second cell) there is a small jump in the table. And after that, everything scrolls butter smooth.

Xib file
[XibFile screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJZpe.png)

Comment: is there any image in third cell ?

Comment: All the cells in this demo app are the same. No Image files. Just labels, buttons, UIViews, Stackviews. I have added a screenshot of my xib file

Comment: try testing it on real device rather than on simulator.

Comment: It was running on my 6s. I recorded it using quickTime so it looks like it was on the simulator. Cheers,

Comment: Are your performing any operations on the Layer of any of the views? If so then do this

`self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;`
    
`self.view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`

Comment: I am not doing any operation. I am just displaying the views for this demo.

Comment: I have the same problem. I dequeue cells in advance (viewDidLoad) in order to rule out the xib loading but it did not help. In my case, using screen recording while scrolling fixes the issue. So odd and I cannot really tell user to turn on the screen recording for optimal experience X)